# multiple use of the same ResultSet in Java

Tags: java, derby

Is it bad habit to use the same `ResultSet` object in Java? Why or why not? //It seems to be my only option here, as I am trying to query a table for its record count, and then query a view of that table; I don't know how to change the view.

In other words, is

```
ResultSet myResultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM table");
myResultSet.next();
int recordCount = myResultSet.getInt(1);
myResultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tableView");
//set other variables based on contents of fetched view
```

a bad idea?

Comment: It depends. Please post a sourcecode example. I am asking because I believe you might use different ResultSet objects without realizing it. This might also be more relevant to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: It is completely depends upon your requirement and it is not at all a bad habit when your usage is perfect

Comment: Is my usage (show in the example) "perfect"? I added it right after you posted this comment; I should have anticipated the responses and done so immediately, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you have posted does not "reuse the same `ResultSet`", it simply discards one `ResultSet` object and then uses the same variable to hold a reference to a different `ResultSet` created by the second `executeQuery`.  It would be good coding practice to call `close()` on the first result set before you overwrite the reference with the second one, but this is not strictly necessary because

> A `ResultSet` object is automatically closed when the `Statement` object that generated it is closed, **re-executed**, or used to retrieve the next result from a sequence of multiple results.

(from the [ResultSet JavaDoc documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html), my bold)

Comment: Thank you very much; I was trying to look on there for that same type of response. //Multithreading is very hard for most of us humans...

Answer (score 4):

> Is it bad habit to use the same ResultSet object in Java?

I would say it depends on the particular requirement and way of coding .

I believe what you are looking for is a scrollable [ResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) which was introduced as a new and improved feature in **Version 2.0/2.1 (integrated into JDK 1.2)**, which comes in two flavors : [TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE) and [TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE).

If we see the code you have posted :

```
ResultSet myResultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM table");
myResultSet.next();
int recordCount = myResultSet.getInt(1);
myResultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tableView");
```

What you are basically doing is setting the `myResultSet` reference variable to a new `ResultSet` object. I don't see anything bad in that , perhaps , someone more enlightened than me can point out .

Answer (score 2):

Once you are done with the table, you can close the respective result set. And the same reference can be used for another table.

If you want to query table and view simultaneously then you will require two separate result sets.

Comment: I have tried something like `SELECT count(*) FROM table CROSS JOIN (SELECT * FROM view)`, which, according to the Derby Reference Manual, should return a one-row table that has n+1 columns, where n is the number of columns in the one-row view. (The documentation states that `A CROSS JOIN is a JOIN operation that produces the Cartesian product of two tables. `)

Comment: In this particular case, you can iterate the result with single resultset by calling executeQuery() method of prepared statement.

Comment: For some reason, by using that String as an argument of `statement.executeQuery()` (not a prepared statement) I get some Syntax Error near the end saying that it encountered <EOF> at the end

Comment: I have, before that, `Statement statement = connection.createStatement();`. I don't know about posting ALL of my example code (which I think this is what you mean), even though I am using it as example code.

Comment: I think, your code should be like this:


Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(String sql);


Can you paste the full stack of the exception that you are getting?

Comment: How is this going to help? I would have to post MY WHOLE PROGRAM for this to even benefit you searching for the problem. I have, where you put String sql, the statement I have first mentioned.

Comment: I posted the problem I am having with my single query as a [new question][link].

[link] : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17485975/problems-with-cross-join